# how to add and remove jqueryui tab with knockout.js

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I got hint from [this sample codes](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NLGm8/)

Attached the codes here

```
<button id='add'>add</button>

<div data-bind="template: 'tabsTmpl'"></div>
<script id="tabsTmpl" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="jqTabs: { fx: { } }">
        <ul>
            {{each tabs}}
            <li>
                <a href="#tab-${id}">${id}</a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
        {{each tabs}}
        <div id="tab-${id}" >${id}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
<script>
        ko.bindingHandlers.jqTabs = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var options = valueAccessor() || {};
                $(element).tabs(options);
            }
        };

        function TabItem(id) {
            this.id = ko.observable(id);
        }

        var viewModel = {
            tabs: ko.observableArray([new TabItem(1), new TabItem(2), new TabItem(3)])
        };


        $(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            $('#add').click(function () {
                viewModel.tabs.push(new TabItem(viewModel.tabs().length + 1));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The author of above codes used jquery template engine, but I want to use knockout.js' native template engine, so I changed html codes as follow :

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="jqTabs: { fx: { } }">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: tabs">
            <li>
                <a data-bind="attr:{href:'#tab-' + id()}, text:id"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: tabs -->
        <div data-bind="attr:{id:'tab-'+id()}, text:id"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But, it does not work.
What I am doing wrong with native template engine?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a functioning version: http://jsfiddle.net/NLGm8/32/

One of the trickiest things about Knockout integration with jQuery is the timing of when the plugin expects DOM elements to be there and when Knockout will have rendered them.

Often I find a setTimeout around the plugin initialization will do the trick, and it did here.

Comment: Thanks John, can you look at this codes http://jsfiddle.net/outia24/NLGm8/33/  I added button to add tab, but it does not work as expected

Comment: The problem was that the custom binding was not re-evaluating.  By adding a dependency we can fix that.  Then we need to make sure we cleanup any existing tabs before initializing the tabs.  I also switched to 'update' in the custom binding (as we want to react to changes). Here is the final result: http://jsfiddle.net/NLGm8/34/

Comment: It is perfect, John. BTW can you elaborate more why 'if:tabs().length>0' code needed? I still don't get it.

Comment: Hi Ray.  In your fiddle the `jqTabs` binding is at the div level, but the only reference to the `tabs` observable was inside - on the ul. When you pushed a new entry into `tabs` the `foreach` binding was notified, but `jqTabs` was not.  By adding an `if` on `jqTabs` we created a dependency such that the `update` method would be called when `tabs` changed.  So a new tab resulted in a new `li` being created (by the `foreach`), which then was transformed into a tab by `jqTabs` update.  Did that make sense?